# How many possible combinations can i get from this hash?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, big-o

Here is a the combination:

```
OPTIONS = {
  :tense =>     [:present,    :past,       :future],
  :person =>    [:third,      :first,      :second],
  :plurality => [:singular,   :plural],
  :diathesis => [:active,     :passive],
  :mood =>      [:indicative, :imperative, :subjunctive],
  :aspect =>    [:habitual,   :perfective, :habitual, :progressive, :perfect, :prospective]  
}
```

There is only one rule, one value can be used from one key

so that means these pairs are possible

```
1. :present, :third, :singular, :active, :indicative, :habitual
2. :present, :third
3. :present, :third, :indicative, :habitual 
4. ... etc
```

however these ones are not:

```
1. :present, :past, :future
2. :first, :third, :present
3. ... etc
```

If there is a formula please share

All answers are appreciated.

Comment: How many items may be present in each "pair"?  From your first example it seems like you're looking for all combinations of two or more items from the set of array values?

Comment: Sorry just saw your question, it could be one, two or all keys values with no more than one value

Comment: `:present, :third, :singular, :active, :indicative, :habitual`, etc is not a pair.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatoric (math), not programming

Comment: Jackie, it may be too late to rescue your question, but if you want to try, you need to do two things: 1) frame your question in terms of a Ruby coding problem, and 2) be more precise in your description of the problem.  I'm guessing that you want to create an array of unique arrays, where each inner array draws at most one element from the value (an array) of each key/value pair in OPTIONS.  You need to say something like that.  Clarify by editing your question, not by adding a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of all combinations you can do the following:

```
OPTIONS.values.map{ |v| v + [nil]}.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten).map(&:compact).uniq
```

What it does is:

- adds `nil` to each list (the option that it is not chosen)
- creates every combination of one of each list
- the above creates lists of lists, so we flatten them to a list
- remove any `nil`s from any combintation

Sample combination:

```
[:future, :first, :active, :perfect]
```

The above will include the empty combination (`[]`), but you can add `.select { |cmb| cmb.length > 1 }` if you want to include only combinations with two elements or more.

Now you can simply count:

```
OPTIONS.values.map{ |v| v + [nil]}.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten).uniq.
  map(&:compact).count
# => 3456
OPTIONS.values.map{ |v| v + [nil]}.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten).uniq.
  map(&:compact).select { |cmb| cmb.length > 1 }.count
# => 3437
```

**Update**
@EyalSchneider has suggested that I add his formula to my answer, so that it would be more complete:

```
(|A1|+1)*(|A2|+1)*...*(|An|+1) - 1
```

Essentially what it means is that the number of combinations in `product` is the product of all the sizes of all the relevant arrays:

```
OPTIONS.values.map { |x| x.length + 1 }.inject(:*) - 1
# => 4031
```

Comment: Hmmm.... the this item is duplicated...

`:present, :third, :singular, :active, :indicative, :habitual`

Comment: Interesting... don't know why that happens, added `uniq` to remove duplicates

Comment: Damn, I'm puzzled, your answer is a ruby answer, basically I can grab this code.... but the one that got more hits is more academically correct... hmmmm

Comment: @JackieChan - just figured out why there are duplicated items - you have `:habitual` twice in `:aspect`...

Comment: @JackieChan the academic answer could not have figured that out ;-). If you think this is the correct answer - accept it. The number of votes is not the only parameter for the best answer for you.

Comment: @UriAgassi: add the formula to your answer, and then it can be accepted as a more complete answer.

Comment: Good answer Uri.  I particularly like your use of `inject`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly the question, the formula is:

```
(|A1|+1)*(|A2|+1)*...*(|An|+1) - 1
```

Where `Ai` stands for set #i (e.g. tense, person), and `|Ai|` is the size of set `Ai`.
The idea is that every set of size N has N+1 options - either one of the N values, or no value from this set. The combinations are unique because any two combinations differ in the representative of at least one set.

The minus one at the end is for eliminating the empty combination.
With the data you provided, the result is 4031.

Comment: You should probably explain `|foo|` as being "magnitude of set called foo" . . . the answer is succinct (and correct IMO), but may use notation that OP is not familiar with

Comment: @NeilSlater: you are right, I'll add more details.

Comment: The empty "pair" was not ruled out by the OP, was it ? ;-)

Comment: Can you edit your answer, I mistakenly pressed down button, now I can't change it.

Just make a dummy update, and I will vote up your answer.

It's 1AM in Sydney Friday :)